# Checkbox condition in react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

im trying to put a condition on my checkboxs , i want to set the number of checks for each state

so here i have my JSON file that has 4 elements

```js
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "key": "Viande hachee",
    "checked": false,
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/RuVD8qi.png   "

  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "key": "Escalope pane",
    "checked": false,
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/WNeYn6d.png"

  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "key": "Escalope grille",
    "checked": false,
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/iFpCySw.png"

  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "key": "Cordon  bleu",
    "checked": false,
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/iRo6ivZ.png"

  }
]
```

this is my code :

```js
export default class Commande extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {

            data: TacosData,
            SelectedItem: [],
            taille: "M"
        };
    }
    onchecked(id) {
        const data = this.state.data
        const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
        data[index].checked = !data[index].checked
        this.setState(data)
    }
    renderTacos(item, key) {

        return (

            <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: normalize(20), marginRight: normalize(20 )}} key={key} onPress={() => { this.onchecked(item.id) }}>
                <Image style={styles.rednerImg} source={{ uri: item.image }} ></Image>
                <Text style={styles.rednertext}>{item.key}</Text>
                <CheckBox value={item.checked}
                    style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: 0.8 }, { scaleY: 0.8 }], }}
                    onValueChange={() => { this.onchecked(item.id) }}
                    tintColors={{ true: '#D05A0B', false: 'black' }}

                />
            </TouchableOpacity>

        )

    }
render() {
        return (
                            <FlatList

                                data={this.state.data}
                                style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', }}
                                numColumns={2}
                                renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderTacos(item)}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                            />
)}
}
```

For example this the state of `taille` is `'M'` then i can only check only 1 checkox ,
is this case im able to check all of the checkboxes
is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you said if...

> the state of taille is 'M' then i can only check only 1 checkox , is
> this case im able to check all of the checkboxes

then code is my answer to handle that case

```
onchecked(id) {
  const data = this.state.data

  const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id === id)

  if (this.state.taille == 'M') {
    for(const i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (i != index) {
        data[i].checked = false // reset other checkboxes to unchecked, so when taille is 'M' only clicked checkbox that can be true
      }
    }
  }

  data[index].checked = !data[index].checked

  this.setState({data})
}
```

Edit responding case based to the following comment

```
onchecked(id) {
  const data = this.state.data

  const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id === id)
   
  let maxCheck = undefined

  if (this.state.taille == 'M') {
     maxCheck = 1
  } else if (this.state.taille == 'L') {
     maxCheck = 2
  }

  let checkboxCheckedTotal = 0

  for(const i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].checked) {
         checkboxCheckedTotal++
      }
   }

   if (maxCheck == undefined || data[index].checked || checkboxCheckedTotal < maxCheck) {
      data[index].checked = !data[index].checked
   }

   this.setState({data})
}
```

Comment: That's what im looking for ! but let's say for example taille is 'L' , how can i change the number of checks to 2 not only 1 ?

Comment: please see my additional edit, maybe it will need to be tested more and improved, you need to unchecked all checkboxes though when taille is changed

Comment: to prevent bug, users from checking all 4 then change to 'M'